# How to resume/Restart a thread in Java after an exception is caught?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, error-handling

Lately, I have been playing around in Java's Networking and Threading capabilities, just as a background I am trying to develop a multi-threaded chatting application.

The problem is that when a client sends a message that uses a wrong format ex :
"UserID#Message" instead of "UserID*Message" an exception is thrown, the thread Halts completely, the client needs to close his session and re-open it again to re-establish a connection with the server instead of resuming after the error, and I can't resume it.

Here is the Server Code:

```
package AdvanceThreading.Server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;

    private DataInputStream messageFromClientToHandler;
    private DataOutputStream messageFromHandlerToRecipient;

    private int port;
    private static int userID;
    private ArrayList<ClientHandler> clientList;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        this.userID = 0;
        clientList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                messageFromClientToHandler = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                messageFromHandlerToRecipient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                String userName = messageFromClientToHandler.readUTF();

                messageFromHandlerToRecipient.writeInt(userID);

                ClientHandler client = new ClientHandler(userID, userName, this, socket, messageFromClientToHandler, messageFromHandlerToRecipient);

                clientList.add(client);

                //Should set client.setUncaughtExceptionHandler();

                client.start();

                userID = userID + 1;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public ServerSocket getServerSocket() {
        return serverSocket;
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public DataInputStream getMessageFromClientToHandler() {
        return messageFromClientToHandler;
    }

    public DataOutputStream getMessageFromHandlerToRecipient() {
        return messageFromHandlerToRecipient;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public static int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public ArrayList<ClientHandler> getClientList() {
        return clientList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server(5050);
    }
}
```

Client Handler Code:

```
package AdvanceThreading.Server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private int clientID;
    private String clientName;
    private boolean loggedIn;

    private Socket socket;

    private Server server;

    private DataInputStream messageFromClientToHandler;
    private DataOutputStream messageFromHandlerToRecipient;


    public ClientHandler(int clientID, String clientName, Server server, Socket socket, DataInputStream messageFromClientToHandler, DataOutputStream messageFromHandlerToRecipient) {
        this.clientID = clientID;
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.server = server;
        this.socket = socket;
        this.messageFromClientToHandler = messageFromClientToHandler;
        this.messageFromHandlerToRecipient = messageFromHandlerToRecipient;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String receivedFromClient;
        StringTokenizer tokenize = null;

        while (true) {
            try {
                receivedFromClient = messageFromClientToHandler.readUTF();

                System.out.println(receivedFromClient);

                tokenize = new StringTokenizer(receivedFromClient, "#");
                String recipient = tokenize.nextToken();
                int recipientID = Integer.parseInt(tokenize.nextToken());
                String message = tokenize.nextToken();

                //Need to handle exception of client not found.

                for (ClientHandler client : server.getClientList()) {
                    if (client.getClientID() == recipientID && client.isLoggedIn()) {
                        client.getMessageFromHandlerToRecipient().writeUTF(this.clientName + ": " + message);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                while (tokenize != null && tokenize.hasMoreTokens())
                    tokenize.nextToken();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loggedIn;
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    }

    public int getClientID() {
        return clientID;
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public Server getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    public DataInputStream getMessageFromClientToHandler() {
        return messageFromClientToHandler;
    }

    public DataOutputStream getMessageFromHandlerToRecipient() {
        return messageFromHandlerToRecipient;
    }
}
```

The Main thing i want to do that if a client using a terminal (Ex : CMD) does an error i want to catch the error handle it, and resume his session on the same terminal so that he doesn't have to reconnect to the server again.

Comment: side note: an exception can be thrown from the terminal session having IO issue, in that case, there is no way to reuse the same terminal session

Comment: So, basically it's up to me to ensure that a client doesn't do a mistake?

Comment: you can easily address it by adding runtime exception try catch block for any conversion related exception, I will drop you code snipped in a second

Comment: Once a thread terminates (ie. uncaught exception) it cannot be resumed. There has to be logic inside the code running on the thread to "handle error and continue appropriately" or outside the thread to "start a new thread". Catching an exception does not "pause" a thread; rather, that's just a standard flow control operation in the same vein as if-something-failed-then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion you can catch any invalid related data excpetion with RuntimeException:

```
  StringTokenizer tokenize = new StringTokenizer(receivedFromClient, "#");

        try {
            String recipient = tokenize.nextToken();

            int recipientID = Integer.parseInt(tokenize.nextToken());
            String message = tokenize.nextToken();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

            //ask client to resend the data
            continue
        }
```

Comment: Thanks dude, i did as you said i handled the run-time exception within the scope of the Client handler.